# Why do we have to believe in Jinn? العقيدة vs الايمان

Tags: hadith, jinn, imaan, aqidah

I'm looking for a reference. As we all know that the Iman الايمان according the well known hadith of Jibril (for example in Sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/1)) doesn't include the belief in Jinn! I would like to know if there's a clear reference quoting that **we have to believe** in them.

**EDIT:**
I know they are quoted in Qur'an and i have no doubt about their existence because of this, but i have a problem: as for me a believer is the one who believes in Allah, in His angels, in His Books, in His Apostles, in the Day of Judgment, and you affirm your faith in the Divine Decree about good and evil. which are mentioned in Hadith Jibril. But in 'Aqida ('Aqeeda) books Jinn are quoted and this makes me think that 'Aqida العقيدة is set higher than Iman (faith)! While i don't know of any hadith quoting 'Aqida!

Maybe i should add this: Is 'Aqida higher placed then Iman: If so, when am i a m'umin (a believer) then?

I hope now i made things clear!

Comment: Have you considered the fact that Imaan on Quran entails Imaan on its Chapter 72, whose subject and title contains Jinn?

Comment: Makes sense, you believe chapter 72 is the word of God and then say I dont believe in Jinn. What does one make up of that stance?

Comment: For example in the book i quoted they are telling things about Jinn which i can hardly believe: I mean ok Sulayman (peace be upon him) as Prophet would might have possibilities to communicate etc. with them but how could Ibn Taymya or other scholars etc. talk about some encounters and experiences with Jinn. I mean why should a disbelief in something apparently not mentioned to be a basic of our belief turn somebody into a disbeliever?

Comment: What if someone instead somehow believed the jinns are angels or like fallen angels as Christians do think Satan is? Tabari seems to have some related quotes about { كانَ مِنَ الـجِنّ }: "وقال آخرون: هم سبط من الـملائكة قبـيـلة، وكان اسم قبـيـلته الـجنّ" ... [Mentioned here](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/18/al-kahf/50/al-tabari)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The belief in Jinn, first and foremost, is established by chapter 72 (Al-Jinn), of Quran. The subject of that chapter sheds light on Jinn and their relation with God and humans. Muslims believe the chapters of Quran were named by the Prophet (puh) himself and as such through Allah's guidance. The fact that it is named "Al-Jinn" bears a huge weight when it comes to belief in Jinn.

However, probably the pinnacle of belief in Jinn is chapter 55 (Al-Rahaman). How many times the following verse is repeated?

> Which of the powers of your Lord will you twain – you men and jinn –
> then deny? ([55:17](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.maududi/55:17))

The Quran itself explains as to who are being addressed in these verses.

> **O company of jinn and men**, if you have the power to go beyond the
> bounds of the heavens and the earth, go beyond them! Yet you will be
> unable to go beyond them for that requires infinite power. ([55:33](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.maududi/55:33))

There are other references to Jinn in other chapters, for example Al-Naml. There is no room to disbelieve that Jinn exist. It does not suffice to say "they (might) exist." They most certainly do in **Orthodox Islam**. In orthodox Islam, to disbelieve in Jinn is tantamount to rejecting all the verses of Quran that speak of them. Not just the Quran, but there is a plethora of narrations in the books of Ahadith. Just one example:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) used to say, "I seek refuge (with YOU) by Your 'Izzat,
> None has the right to be worshipped but You Who does not die while the
> Jinns and the human beings die." [bukhari/97/13](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/13)

#### In Modernist Strands

The case of the Modernists is sometimes different. For example, [Ghulam Ahmed Pervez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghulam_Ahmed_Pervez) translated those verses in the Quran which are generally associated with "miracles", "angles" and "jinns" rationally as metaphors, without appealing to the supernatural. However, other modernists have rejected these ideas, e.g. [Concept of JINN & Ghulam Ahmed Pervez - Javed Ahmed Ghamidi](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xtv7t8_concept-of-jinn-ghulam-ahmed-pervez-javed-ahmed-ghamidi_webcam) (unfortunately in Urdu language).

More well-known is the neo-Mutazillite [Syed Ahmed Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syed_Ahmad_Khan), who built up a comprehensive naturalistic metaphysics, explaining away the so-called supernatural component in phenomena like miracles, prayers and their acceptance by God, sufistic illuminations, prophetic visions, angels, heaven and hell, and so on ([source](http://www.allamaiqbal.com/publications/journals/review/oct95/1.htm)). According to Syed, *Jinn does not refer to paranormal but is used for wild savages living in inaccessible regions or far away from civilized communities... Fire which is the stuff of Jinns is not actual fire but the force and energy of lower passions and emotions* ([source](http://prr.hec.gov.pk/Chapters/669-8.pdf)). In a nutshell, **wicked humans are Jinn**.

#### Conclusion

To the best of my knowledge, grand majority comprising of modernist and orthodox scholarship unanimously interpret the word Jinn in Quran to what is the [general understanding of the word Jinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn), i.e. super-natural creatures. Whether naive rejection of supernatural or "*interpreting it away*," leads to disbelief depends on ones personal philosophical bents and choice of orthodoxy. In modernists strands of thoughts, it is in fact the correct worldview. Orthodoxy will have severe problems due to the overwhelming consensus and reference.

**EDIT:**
To answer the question: As we find the belief in Jinn in 'Aqida and not in Iman, is 'Aqida higher placed then Iman.

To see a priority between creed and faith is incorrect, rather absurd, because Aqida (creed) is a set of beliefs and Imaan (faith) is the willing act of confessing confidence in the creed through tongue and completely trusting it with heart. If belief in Jinn is in the creed then faith is incomplete without having trust in it.

Comment: This means faith makes me a believer. So what's the matter of the salafis attacking others for having a bad creed?

Comment: The answer is in your question "bad creed." People exhibit faith in satanic religions (creeds). Faith in such a creed would make you a believer(of that religion).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to ask whether you have to believe tales of Jin narrated by people. The answer is no, you don't have to believe Jin tales and stories narrated by people of today, nor by people of the past, the only exception being the prophet and what is narrated in the Quran.

Answer (score -1):

If it mentioned in the Qur'an then we have to believe in it. If you do not believe in jinns, then you are rejecting at least a whole chapter of the Qur'an. Rejecting even a single word of the Qur'an can be very dangerous a you are rejecting the blessed words of Allah. Therefore as a Muslim we have to beleive in Jinns just as they have been mentioned in the Qur'an e.g. the story of Solomon (AS) where we are told that the Jinns were in a different world to us. We are also told that the Jinns to have to believe in Allah, the Messenger and the Quran. And so they must exist.

Answer (score -1):

ٍSure, we have to believe in Jinns because it is mentioned in Kuraan

```
{قُلْ أُوحِيَ إِلَيَّ أَنَّهُ اسْتَمَعَ نَفَرٌ مِّنَ الْجِنِّ}[الجنّ: 1]
```

And as we are Muslims:

We believe that Jinns can affect on the humans sometimes

But cannot per example uttered with the human tongue or things like control the human actions and so on ...

these things are Myths and is not from Islam

**EDIT :**

And i would like to tell you something :

That if the Jinns are mentioned in Kuraan like the Ayah that i tell in the answer :

You should search in the true books and you don't have to search in these books like Sahih Muslim because they are not reliable and are not from a Infallible person like Prophet Mohammad or Imam Ali

Only Quran and the true Hadis of ahl lbeit is reliable in Islam

And for Ahl lBeit the Jinns are mandatory in Iman of the person because it is a thing mentioned in Quran

```
والحمد لله رب العالمين
```

Comment: sorry but i can't see an answer for my question: It might answer the headline but not my question

Comment: ok when u update ur question it is clear now , please take a look at my edited answer now

Comment: You are wrong in calling Sahih Muslim 'Not reliable' and such without a reference from some agreed upon authority. But your comment next to it proves you are not a Sunni, hence why you say such a thing. This site is not for such debate about whether Sunni or Shia are wrong. You must avoid such statements and please do not throw your own opinions in our faces. Thank you.